# Fullscreen with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, selector, fullscreen

I'm trying to make an element fullscreen with an onclick-event. It's working well with the following code in the click event function:

```
var element = document.getElementById('fullscreenDiv');
fullScreen(element);
```

The fullScreen function handles the request correctly. But when I try to use the very same code, but subsitute the document.getElementById with a simple jquery selector, nothing happens:

```
var element = $('#fullscreenDiv');
fullScreen(element);
```

I don't see the reason for that behaviour. Has anyone an explanation for that? Thanks for your answers!

The fullScreen function looks like that:

```
function fullScreen(element) {
    if(element.requestFullScreen) {
      element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen ) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you finding any error message in console ?

Comment: Depends what your function is expecting, can we see the function please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fullScreen()` function expects to get a DOMNode element, not a *jQuery* object like that you are passing through, if you were to pass through the Node element that the jQuery Object *selects*:

```
var $element = $('#fullscreenDiv');
fullScreen($element.get(0));
```

This'll work as your first snippet intended too. To give you a little more understanding to why this is happening, jQuery objects are a *collection* of raw DOM Elements, using [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or `[index]`, accesses those collected elements.

Comment: Or simply `var element = $('#fullscreenDiv')[0];`

Comment: Awesome! Both solutions are working. Thanks! Also for the explanation!